# Add the discount total for each item as WooCommerce order item metadata

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders, discount

I need to add in order metadata the amount of the discount for each product individually. For example, There are ten products in the order. The user has applied a coupon discount to the products. The total amount of the discount was calculated (if there are products on_sale, they were not taken into discount calculate).

But in the end, we got a total discount. And I need to split this discount for all the products that received it and even write this value into order item metadata.

Why don't I even have a sample code? I just don't know where to start. The only thing I think is to take the total discount, divide it by the number of products that can have a discount (these are all products in the order except on_sale), And add the resulting number to the product meta. But there is a problem, I'm not sure if this is the right solution. Could you please share any advice on how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start with [`woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` action hook](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.1.0/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L489) where you will be able to set custom order item meta data. This hook has 4 arguments:

- `$item` the order item (object),
- `$cart_item_key` the cart item key (string),
- `$values` the cart item (array),
- `$order` the order (object).

So you can get from the cart item `$values` the discounted line item totals using:

```
$line_discount     = $value['line_subtotal'] - $value['line_total'];
$line_discount_tax = $value['line_subtotal_tax'] - $value['line_tax'];
```

Then for example all together to save the line discount total as custom order item meta data:

```
// Save Line item discount as custom order item meta data
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'action_checkout_create_order_line_item', 10, 4 );
function action_checkout_create_order_line_item( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    $line_discount     = $value['line_subtotal'] - $value['line_total'];
    $line_discount_tax = $value['line_subtotal_tax'] - $value['line_tax'];
    
    $item->update_meta_data( '_line_discount', $line_discount + $line_discount_tax );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Then you can get it from an order item object `$item` using the `WC_Data` method `get_meta()` like:

```
 $line_discount = $item->get_meta('_line_discount');
```

Related: [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

Comment: Hello, this solution works like a charm. But I just can't understand. If I apply a coupon the amount of the discount is displayed for all items individual without any trouble. For example:

1.25
0.9
3.25

But we also have an individual custom discount. :
And when this discount is applied, nothing is displayed.
0
0
0
It is strange because the sum of an individual discount is calculated not from what discount is used, but from the difference between the subtotal amount and the total. As I get right:  $line_discount     = $value['line_subtotal'] - $value['line_total'];

Comment: Oh, sorry I  could not compliment the comment link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65097517/apply-a-welcome-discount-to-non-on-sale-items-in-woocommerce
A welcome discount is calculated based on this code. And for some reason, it is not taken into account. Here is a link for example: https://prnt.sc/10mj1mp

Comment: @VictorSokoliuk The link provided in your comment is using **a negative fee**, which is a trick that WooCommerce does not recommend using, and that **is not really a discount**. Fees are not applied at item level and even when they are negative are still Fees, but not discounts… That's why you get 0 0 0 0

Comment: So, as I get it right, at this level, I will not get to these values in any way? And the total/subtotal amount of the cart will not give me anything in this case. And there is only one way out to change the welcome bonus?

Comment: @VictorSokoliuk 1) *"I will not get to these values in any way?"*: You could try to split the negative fee amount based on cart item line total amount and add it to your custom field. 2) *"cart item total/subtotal amount"*: doesn't take fees into account. 3) *"And there is only one way out to change the welcome bonus?"*: I don't catch (?).

Comment: 1) It's really, thanks for the idea, I'll try to split the negative fee.
3) Sorry. I mean, if I can not resolve this issue, then I will have to abandon the welcome bonus.

Comment: @VictorSokoliuk For the Welcome bonus, instead you could auto-apply/remove a coupon "welcome bonus" of 5% based on your conditions. I have made some answer(s) related if I remember. But you need to allow this coupon to be applied with others. This will solve the problem.

Comment: Hi! Here is my solution:
https://prnt.sc/10qvmbn It's not very elegant, but it works. Thank you for helping.